# a problem related to continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

Let $f$ be a function defined in $[0,1]$ such that $f(0) > 0 > f(1)$. Suppose there is a continuous function $g$ on $[0,1]$ such that $f + g$ is increasing. Prove that the equation $f(x)=0$ has at least one solution in $[0,1]$. I tried to consider another continuous function in order to use the theorem of intermediate values but I failed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Let $f(x)=2-x,\;g(x)=2x$. It meets both conditions, but...

Comment: @IvanNeretin $f(1)=1>0$

Comment: Sorry about that, didn't notice the second part. Well, then the question has its merit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An increasing function has only jump discontinuities, with left and right limits at every point:
$$ 
\forall a \in (0, 1] : \lim_{x \to a-} (f(x) + g(x)) \le f(a) + g(a) \, ,\\
\forall a \in [0, 1) : f(a) + g(a) \le \lim_{x \to a+} (f(x) + g(x)) \, .
$$
But $g$ is continuous, so that
$$ 
\forall a \in (0, 1] : \lim_{x \to a-} f(x) \le f(a) \, , \\
\forall a \in [0, 1) : f(a)  \le \lim_{x \to a+} f(x) \, .
$$
Now define
$$
 c = \sup \{ x \mid f(x) > 0 \} \, .
$$
Then
$$ 
c > 0 \implies 0 \le f(c) \, ,\\
c < 1 \implies f(c) \le 0 \, .
$$
Since $f(0) > 0 > f(1)$ is given, the only possibility is that $0 < c < 1$ and $f(c) = 0$.

Comment: you defined c such that f(c)#0 and u find that f(c)=0 ? thanks in advance

Comment: @AbdeAe: $c$ is defined as the *supremum* of the set $\{ x \mid f(x) > 0 \}$. Using the preceding properties you can show that $f(c) = 0$. (Drawing a picture might help.)

Comment: got it, thanks a lot.